Remapping Command key to CTRL key on on Windows does not work via SharpKeys
I connect to Windows server via Apache Guacamole from my MacBook and would like my Mac's Command key to work as a Ctrl key in Windows. Otherwise each time I need to copy paste I have to do Command+C (on Mac) and then CTRL+V (on Windows).
I installed SharpKeys on Windows, however the "Type key" feature does not detect Command key (neither Option key). So I added remap manually, and successfully write to registry, however it does not work.
I am remapping Special: Left Windows (E0_58) to Special: Left Ctrl (00_1D)

Any idea why is it not working?

You might try https://keycode-visualizer.netlify.app/ to check the keycode

@DrMoishePippik, just tried, it does not register anything, just like SharpKeys.
